# How do I find the PID of a specific shell script that is sleeping?

Tags: linux, shell, process

I understand I can use `pgrep -fl example.sh` to find the PID of the script `example.sh`, but this doesn't work if `example.sh` is something like the following:

```
(while true; do
  sleep 5
done) &
```

Running `./example.sh` and then `pgrep -fl example.sh` doesn't return any input. How would I find the PID of `example.sh` while it's sleeping?

Answer (score 1):

You might have noticed that your `example.sh` script exits immediately. This is because in this case the `sleep` command got send to background  via `&`.

Your script is not waiting for `sleep` to finish before executing the next command in sequence.

`sleep` will not work in its intended way (as a delay) in this case.

**There is absolutely no reason to run `sleep` in background.**

---

**Note:** `pgrep -fl processname` will not only output the PID, but also the process  name

```
 -f, --full
              The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.
-l, --list-name
              List the process name as well as the process ID.  (pgrep only.)
```